# Static (fake) random generator

Tags: haskell, random

For testing purposes of a `RandomGen`-reliant function I need a `RandomGen` instance which will return the numbers I tell it to on instantiation so that I could compare the results of a tested function to the correct ones. I.e. on each call to `random` I want this function to return the next number from a list `[5, 8, 2, 6, 6]` (it may throw an error if it reaches the end or it may cycle). I expect an instance of that generator to be created as simply as `StaticGen [5, 8, 2, 6, 6]`.

I am wondering if there exists such a library or maybe if I should take some different approach at my testing.

*On Updates: turns out I originally stated the question wrong by specifying the `next` function instead of `random` as the one I wanted to return the values from a list. My apologies.*

Comment: As an alternative to creating a new `RandomGen` instance, maybe testing with a fixed `StdGen` would suit your needs, `staticGen = mkStdGen 13` for example.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yeah I thought about that, but then the values actually returned by the generator still wouldn't be evident in the code, which is obviously a requirement in my case.

Comment: If the values need to be evident in the code, that does indeed not work. Out of curiosity: Why do they have to be evident?

Comment: @DanielFischer In HUnit `assertEqual` tests I always have a hardcoded expected value compared to the result of the tested function processing the hardcoded input data. Having all the information there at hand makes correction and extension of tests more convenient.

Comment: I would suggest, if possible, 1) try to refactor the function so that it takes raw numbers, and then create a convenience function that deals with the generator, and/or 2) try writing property-based tests. Hard-coded test data is OK but isn't the ideal way to test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you could distribute such a library.  But it would be very short.

```
newtype StaticGen = StaticGen [Int]
instance RandomGen StaticGen where
  next (StaticGen (x:xs)) = (x, StaticGen xs)
  next _ = error "No more random numbers!"
  split x = (x, x)           -- broken, but irrelevant
  genRange _ = (0, maxBound) -- choose your own
```

Well, as mentioned this won't give you out the sequence you pass in.  You could rewrite your functions, so instead of taking a random number generator like this:

```
myFunction :: RandomGen g => g -> a -> (b, g)
```

They work like this instead:

```
myFunction :: forall g. (g -> (Int, g)) -> g -> a -> (b, g)
```

That way you can use it with a random number generator:

```
myFunction random g a
```

Or you can use it with a list:

```
myFunction (\(x:xs) -> (x, xs)) [1,2,3,4] a
```

Comment: Thanks! In my impl I gagged both the `genRange` and `split` functions like so: `split _ = error "Unsupported"`. But it turned out that I stated the question wrong: what I needed actually was a generator the `random` calls to which will return the desired values - not the calls to `next`. My apologies. After analysing the source of `System.Random` I got that to achieve this I'll have to reverse the value of a function `randomIvalInteger` which is computed using logarithms and loops. Since reverse engineering it could turn out to be a nightmare I think the whole thing just isn't worth the effort

Comment: I updated my answer, but you would have to change the signature of your function.